# Same order subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_{n_1} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{n_2}$ where $n_1 \mid n_2$

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{n_1} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{n_2}$ for some integers $n_1$ and $n_2$ with $n_1 \mid n_2$.

Can this group $G$ have two subgroups $H_1$ and $H_2$ such that $|H_1| = |H_2|$ and $H_1 \neq H_2$

Any hint to show existence or non-existence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure.  You can find a subgroup $H$ isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_{n_1}$ inside $\Bbb Z_{n_2}$.  So you have $\Bbb Z_{n_1} \oplus \{0 \}$ as one subgroup and $\{0\} \oplus H$ as the other.

Comment: This doesn't work without the hypothesis $n_1>1$ which ought to have been included ;-)